# Finding all combinations of elements from two sets such that their geometric mean falls into third set

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity, geometric-mean

I have a integers from 1 to `n`. I randomly allot every integer into one of three sets `A`, `B` and `C` (`A ∩ B = B ∩ C = C ∩ A = Ø`). Every integer does belong to one set. So I need to calculate all combination of elements `(a,b)` such that `a ∈ A, b ∈ B`, and the geometric mean of `a,b` belongs to `C`. Basically `sqrt(a*b) ∈ C`.

My solution is to first mark on an array of size `n` whether every element went into set A,B or C. Then I loop through the array for all elements that belong to `A`. When I encounter one, I again loop through for all elements that belong to `B`. If `array[sqrt(a*b)] == C`, then I add `(a, b, sqrt(a,b))` as one possible combination. Then I do the same for the entire array, which is `O(n^2)`.

Is there a more optimal solution possible?

Comment: I temporarily deleted my answer, because it seems that there are some reasons for not answering to this question in the next 3 and a half days (@maraca, please correct me if I misunderstood!). I will undelete it afterwards.

Comment: @qwertyman I'm not sure whether to delete this question and repost after three days?

Comment: I don't know, maybe it's useful to keep it here for a discussion which would clarify whether indeed it should not be answered now. Anyway, I saved my answer, so I won't lose it in case you delete the question. :)

Comment: @qwertyman right thanks, it is because of a contest, the question is worded completely different, but your posted solution is actually exactly the one I had used to pass (before you posted your answer). I also posted the link but you have to register to see it, so I deleted it.

Comment: @qwertyman contest is over! Please post your answer and let me know, upvote is the least I can do.

Comment: @maraca done, thank you for letting me know about the contest end (I hope it went well for you)!

Comment: @qwertyman thanks, done. More or less, gold medal, but don't be too impressed, the top 3% get gold medals and my distance to the top of the crop is still pretty large.

Comment: @maraca congratulations, top 3% is impressive nevertheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with better complexity than O(n^2). The solution sketched here is in O(n * sqrt(n) * log(n)).

The main idea is the following:

- let (a, b, c) be a good solution, *i.e.* one with sqrt(a * b) = c. We can write *a* as a = s * t^2, where *s* is the product of the prime numbers that have odd exponents in *a*'s prime factorization. It's guaranteed that the remaining part of *a* is a perfect square. Since a * b is a perfect square, then b must be of the form s * k^2. For each *a* (there are O(n) such numbers), after finding *s* from the decomposition above (this can be done in O(log(n)), as it will be described next), we can restrict our search for the number *b* to those of the form b = s * k^2, but there are only O(sqrt(n)) numbers like this smaller than *n*. For each pair *a*, *b* enumerated like this we can test in O(1) whether there is a good *c*, using the representation you used in the question.

One critical part in the idea above is decomposing *a* into s * t^2, *i.e.* finding the primes that have odd power in *a*'s factorization.

This can be done using a pre-processing step, that finds the prime factors (but not also their powers) of every number in {1, 2, .. n}, using a slightly modified sieve of Eratosthenes. This modified version would not only mark a number as "not prime" when iterating over the multiples of a prime, but would also append the current prime number to the list of the factors of the current multiple. The time complexity of this pre-processing step is n * sum{for each prime p < n}(1/p) = n * log(log(n)) -- see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Computational_analysis) for details.

Using the result of the pre-processing, which is the list of primes which divide *a*, we can find those primes with odd power in O(log(n)). This is achieved by dividing *a* by each prime in the list until it is no more divisible by that prime. If we made an odd number of divisions, then we use the current prime in *s*. After all divisions are done, the result will be equal to 1. The complexity of this is O(log(n)) because in the worst case we always divide the initial number by 2 (the smallest prime number), thus it will take at most log2(a) steps to reach value 1.

The complexity of the main step dominates the complexity of the preprocessing, thus the overall complexity of this approach is O(n * sqrt(n) * log(n)).

---

Remark: in the decomposition a = s * t^2, *s* is the product of the prime numbers in *a* with odd exponents, but their exponent is not used in *s* (*i.e.* *s* is just the product of those primes, with exponent 1). Only in this situation it is guaranteed that *b* should be of the form s * k^2. Indeed, since a * b = c * c, the prime factorization of the right hand side uses only even exponents, thus all primes from *s* should also appear in *b* with odd exponents, and all other primes from *b*'s factorization should have even exponents.

---

Expanding on the following line: "we can restrict our search for the number *b* to those of the form *b* = *s* * *k*^2, but there are only O(sqrt(n)) numbers like this smaller than n".

Let's consider an example. Imagine that we have something like *n* = 10,000 and we are currently looking for solutions having *a* = 360 = 2^3 * 3^2 * 5. The primes with odd exponent in *a*'s factorization are 2 and 5 (thus *s* = 2 * 5; *a* = 10 * 6^2).

Since *a* * *b* is a perfect square, it means that all primes in the prime factorization of *a* * *b* have even exponents . This implies that those two primes (2 and 5) need to also appear in *b*'s factorization with odd exponents, and the rest of the exponents in *b*'s prime factorization need to be even. Thus *b* is of the form *s* * *k*^2 = 10 * *k* ^ 2.

So we proved that *b* = 10 * *k* ^ 2. This is helpful, because we can now enumerate all the *b* values of this form quickly (in O(sqrt(n)). We only need to consider *k* = 1, *k* = 2, ..., *k* = (int)sqrt(n / 10). Larger values of *k* result in values of *b* larger than *n*. Each of these *k* values determines one *b* value, which we need to verify. Note that when verifying one of these *b* values, it should be first checked whether it indeed is in set B, which can be done in O(1), and whether sqrt(a * b) is in the set C, which can also be done in O(1).

Comment: "we can restrict our search for the number b to those of the form b = s * k^2, but there are only O(sqrt(n)) numbers like this smaller than n. " - Could you please expand on this?

Comment: @maraca Sorry but the page you linked is blocked for me. If it is necessary I can repost the question after 3 days? Should I block this question or delete it till then?

Comment: It's back! :P Could you expand on the following line: "we can restrict our search for the number b to those of the form b = s * k^2, but there are only O(sqrt(n)) numbers like this smaller than n."

Comment: :) I added a discussion in the final part of my answer, let me know if there still are unclear aspects!